# Decreasing sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of positive measurable functions $f_n \downarrow f$ in $(0,1]$ or $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there an example where the Lebesgue integrals have the property
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f_n \not \to \int_0^1 f?
\end{align*}

My attempt so far is to disprove the statement by showing
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f_n \to \int_0^1 f?
\end{align*}
but this requires Dominated Convergence Theorem which would require $f_1$ to be integrable and this is not a given property. Any hints or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: You should change $f_n$ to $f$ on the right side.

Comment: That was sloppy on my part. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)=\frac1  {nx}, f(x)=0$ in $(0,1)$.